# Got an Undefined reducer error in React Native project with Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to use redux in my app for the first time and i set up whole boilerplate for it but i got an error which says `Error: The slice reducer for key "AuthReducer" returned undefined during initialization.`  as it says i checked the state value passed in reducer but i can't figure it out, Here i am adding my code sample.

reducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT, SIGN_UP, MOVIE_ADDED, MOVIE_REMOVED } from './ActionTypes'


const initialMovieState = {
    savedMovies: [
        {
            id: '',
            name: ''
        }
    ]
}

const initialAuthState = {
    userEmail: '',
    userPassword: '',
    userToken: '',
}

export const AuthReducer = (state=initialAuthState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGN_IN:
            return {
                ...state,
                userToken: action.payload.token
            }
        case SIGN_UP: 
            return {
                ...state,
                userEmail: action.payload.email,
                userPassword: action.payload.password
            }
        case SIGN_OUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                userToken: ''
            }
        
        default:
            state
    }

}

export const MovieReducer = (state=initialMovieState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MOVIE_ADDED:
            return {
                ...state,
                savedMovies: state.savedMovies.concat({
                    id: action.payload.movieId,
                    name: action.movieName
                })
            }
        case MOVIE_REMOVED:
            return state.filter(movie => movie.id !== action.payload.movieId)

        default:
            state
    }
}

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
    AuthReducer,
    MovieReducer
})

export default RootReducer
```

actions.js

```
import {SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT, SIGN_UP, MOVIE_ADDED, MOVIE_REMOVED} from './ActionTypes'

export const sign_in = (user) => (
    {
        type: SIGN_IN,
        payload: {
            token: user
        }
    }
)

export const sign_up = (user) => (
    {
        type: SIGN_UP,
        payload: {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }
    }
)

export const sign_out = () => (
    {
        type: SIGN_OUT,
    }
)

export const movie_added = (movie) => (
    {
        type: MOVIE_ADDED,
        payload: {
            movieId: movie.id,
            movieName: movie.name,
        }
    }
)

export const movie_removed = () => (
    {
        type: MOVIE_REMOVED
    }
)
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './Reducer'

const Store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools())

export default Store
```

I've wrapped the whole app in Provider with store as an argument in App.js

SignUpScreen.js

```
import {useDispatch, useStore} from 'react-redux'
import {sign_up} from '../redux/Actions'

const SignUpScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const Store = useStore()

    ...
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if(isValidEmail === true && isValidPass === true && isPassMatched === true){
            console.log(Store.getState())
            dispatch(sign_up({email: email, password: password}))
            console.log(Store.getState())

            navigation.navigate('signin')
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                'Account created.',
                ToastAndroid.LONG,
                ToastAndroid.BOTTOM
            )
        } else {
            ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
                'Invalid Email or Password',
                ToastAndroid.LONG,
                ToastAndroid.BOTTOM
            )
        }

    }
    ...
    return(
    {/* register button */}
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.regBtnCont} onPress={() => handleSubmit()}>
                <Text style={styles.regBtnText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
     )
}
```

Any help will be appriciated, Thank you.

Comment: you should return state in default case, it should be return state; instead of state

Comment: yeah, i updated it. Do you think It is causing the Error?

Comment: Yes as nothing is returned in the initial state, did it fix the issue ?

Comment: yes, it solves the issue. and i am getting a warning which says "Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information" do you now what does that mean, how to solve.